# Center a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a div centered inside another div.

This is the html page:

```
<body>
<div id="divParent">
    <div id="divHeader" >
        <div id="divHeaderText">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divBody">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And this the style:

```
#divHeader {
    background-color: #C7C7C7;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#divBody {
    background-image: url('images/GradientBackground.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 300px;
}
#divHeaderText {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Why the smallest div doesn't left a space on its top?

Comment: I'm asking about center vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

If you're trying to vertically center the `#divHeaderText` within `#divHeader`, try adding `margin-top: 13px;`.

Answer (score 2):

margin:auto does not work for vertical alignment. You must give an exact number in px, em, etc. In your example, this shouldn't be an issue, since you know the height of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

For centering horizontally, you can use text-align:center on inline elements or margin:0 auto with a set width on containers and block level elements.

For vertical centering of text, you can set the line-height property equal to the height of the containing div.

To center a div horizontally, you can apply a margin-top property to space it away into the center.

Please note that design questions are more appropriate for http://www.doctype.com/  as SO is largely geared towards server-side languages and application programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
#divHeaderText {
margin: auto;
width: 90%;
height: 64px; /* 80% of 80px */
margin-top: 8px; /* (80 - 64) / 2 = 8 */
background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? I'm using Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.5.7 and this solution doesn't work. I'm using firebug and I see that divHeaderText is outside divHeader.